# Haskell: dealing with ambiguous imports

Tags: haskell, import

I'm getting ambiguity warnings, sometimes errors, all the time. This is just a clear cut example. I'm using doctest:

```
$ stack exec doctest -- src/Main.hs

<interactive>:6:14:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘stdout’
    It could refer to either ‘Turtle.stdout’,
                         imported from ‘Turtle’ at src/Main.hs:6:1-13
                         (and originally defined in ‘Turtle.Prelude’)
                      or ‘System.IO.stdout’,
                         imported from ‘System.IO’
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.IO.Handle.FD’)
...
Examples: 2  Tried: 2  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
```

It obviously works, at least for the time being, but these warnings are voluminous, annoying, and probably dangerous.

I tried to cope with hiding, like this (Main.hs, all the imports):

```
import Turtle
import Prelude hiding (FilePath)
import System.IO hiding (FilePath, stdout, stderr) -- trying to hide std...
import Text.Regex.TDFA
```

but it makes no difference.

Is there a correct general approach?

Comment: [Johann Tibell recommends](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md) to "[a]lways use explicit import lists or qualified imports for standard and third party libraries".

Comment: Do all-encompassing standard libraries, like Prelude or System.IO, really lend themselves to the explicit import list approach?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov IMO not for prelude - but for `System.IO` etc. it's even a nice documentation - your user can see where some function he/she might not know is imported from

Answer (score 1):

Well you could edit your `.ghci` file and include

```
:m - Prelude
```

this way GHCi should not preload the `Prelude` but like Jubobs I would suggest that you don't reuse those names in the first place or that you import (qualified) with some combination of

```
import Turtle hiding (stdout)
import qualified Turtle as T
import Turtle ( noOverlappingFunc, NonOverlappingType )
```

it's just the minor inconvenience of writing

```
T.stdout
```

instead.

*IMHO* it's not a good idea to hide stuff from the `Prelude` to much - aside from the problems you saw there is always the problem of *peaple* reading your code and their *expectations*

Comment: It does not look like 'minor inconvenience'. It looks like impossibility, as there's no explicit references to stdout in my source code.

Comment: err ... if you don't need it then just use `import Turtle hiding (stdout)` Problem solved ... of course this raises the question why you tried `import System.IO hiding (stdout)` because obviously you did use `Turtle.stdout` in this case

Comment: the *inconvenience* is prepending `T.` which seems not to much burden on the programmer IMO

Comment: In my case Turtle stdout is working: `echo (format ("verbose: "%w) verbose)` is my only output, and that's Turtle through and through. I have to get rid of the standard stdio.